# Adding Subdomain for my ruby on rails server, how to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, debian, subdomain, host

i've got some problems with my ruby on rails server.

It is running under localhost:3333 in my debian vm under a windows8 host.

I've installed apache2 and passengermodul for apache to get ruby. And then I've installed rails.

Now I need a subdomain wich calls the ruby on rails server.

```
for example admin.localhost:3333
```

Is something like that possible? And when how can I configurate it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lvh.me` domain. That domain has a DNS entry that will redirect to localhost. This also works for subdomains, so you can visit `admin.lvh.me:3000` and it will redirect to `localhost:3000` while still having the subdomain available in the Rails request.

The advantage is that you don't have to edit your localhost file.

Answer (score 2):

Add custom hosts with subdomains to the `hosts` file, follow these steps

In your terminal, open `hosts` file

```
cd /etc
sudo nano hosts
```

Add the host as mentioned in the following lines to the hosts file, you can add as many as you want

```
127.0.0.1       admin.localhost
127.0.0.1       subdomain.localhost
```

Save the file, `CTRL + X` then press `Y`

Done.

To run with a custom port, specify the port number while starting the server,

```
rails s -p 3333
```

Now you can run your application with, `admin.localhost:3333`

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah thats clear, hats what I have done already ... but whats with the port 3333? 

and how can I link it to my ruby on rails application running under localhost:3333

Comment: I have edited the answer, you just need to start the rails server specifying the port number with it, `rails s -p 3333`

Comment: yeah how the rails server could be started is clear thanks but how do I link the subdomain admin.localhost to the localhost:3333

Comment: Its already linked, in the hosts file I have used `127.0.0.1` which is the default address for localhost too, try using `admin.localhost:3333` it will still work

Comment: site isn't available ... dosn't load anyting

Comment: Please check whether it is correctly entered in `hosts` file or not because it should definitely work if everything is done perfectly

Comment: added a picture in my question